# Mongodb aggregate with distinct

Tags: mongodb

Being completely new to Mongodb I've searched for an answer and haven't found one to this question. How can I add the option of distinct to an aggregate query?
I have a pedigree database where I would like to find the breeders that bred the most litters in a particular year. I have a field "DOB" that in other queries I can find how many litters were bred in 2013 by "Smith" using this:

```
db.ped.distinct("DOB", {$and:[{"Breeder":{$regex: /Smith/}}, {"DOB-Year":2013}]}).length
```

I can figure out how many litters since multiple dogs by the same breeder with the same birthdate *should* be from the same litter.
I would like to use this in conjunction with an aggregate but haven't been able to figure out what a query would look like. This is what I've used so far but since each document is a dog I'm getting total dogs bred by the breeder that year.

```
db.ped.aggregate( [
    {$match : {"DOB-Year" : 2013}},
    {$group : {_id : "$Breeder", "count" : {$sum : 1}}},
    {$sort : {"count" : -1}},
    {$limit : 15}
] )
```

Is there a way to use `$distinct` in the aggregate query?
Thanks.

**In response to Mario**

I don't think that had quite the result I wanted. I'm not sure what I'm getting exactly, but see what I got here. I've sanitized the data.

```
> db.ped.aggregate([
...     {
...         $match: {
...             "DOB-Year": 2014
...         }
...     },
...     {
...         $group: {
...             _id: {
...                 "Breeder": "$Breeder",
...                 "DOB": "$DOB"
...             },
...             "count": {
...                 $sum: 1
...             }
...         }
...     },
...     {
...         $sort: {
...             "count": -1
...         }
...     },
...     {
...         $limit: 1
...     }
...  ])
{ "_id" : { "Breeder" : "Smith", "DOB" : "09/15/2014" }, "count" : 9 }

> db.ped.distinct("DOB", {"Breeder":{$regex: /Smith/},"DOB-Year":2014}).length
5
```

Obviously what I really want from the first block of code should have said 5 for Smith.
Here is an example of the data I'm using.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55df4a8cc0bfbb6622ae8395"),
    "PedID" : 54321,
    "RegNum" : "12345",
    "RegName" : "My Dog Name",
    "Owner" : "Smith",
    "Sex" : "Dog",
    "Color" : "Black & Tan",
    "Sire" : "My Boy Bob",
    "Dam" : "My Girl Betty",
    "Breeder" : "Smith",
    "DOB" : "10/18/2014",
    "DOB-Year" : 2014
}
```

Comment: Please show a sample document.

Comment: I suspect that some documents have an incorrect `DOB-Year`. Could you perform a `db.ped.find({ "Breeder" : "Smith", "DOB" : "09/15/2014" })` ? You should see 9 documents, could you double check them?

Comment: Ok, I think In understand the issue I'm having but still don't know the correct way to find the result I'm looking for. The `distinct` query I'm running finds how many instances of `DOB` a particular breeder has in a particular year. The aggregate query is finding the breeders with the largest litters in a particular year. I'm looking for the `distinct` ability in my `aggregate` result. Is there a way to do that? Thanks.

Comment: @MikeGross Then i didn't understand what you want to achieve exactly. `group` and `distinct` can't be used together but we should find a way to do what you want. Could you edit your question adding a desired json result?

Comment: I will get some data together later today. Basically, I'm looking to find all the litters from a particular year and then sort them by the breeder. There I will see which breeders bred the most litters in a particular year.

Comment: @MikeGross I think i now get what you mean. Edited my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are willing to group also by `DOB`, you shuld include it in the `_id` of your `group`, like this:

```
db.ped.aggregate([
    {
        $match:{"DOB-Year":2014}
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                "Breeder": "$Breeder",
                "DOB": "$DOB"
            },
            "count": {
                $sum: 1
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: {
            "count": -1
        }
    },
    {
        $limit: 15
    }
 ])
```

NOTE: By the way, notice that in your distinct example the `$and` operator is not needed: you can just do

```
db.ped.distinct("DOB", {"Breeder":{$regex: /Smith/},"DOB-Year":2013}).length
```

because `$and` is implicit when you use just commas and you need it only in special cases

EDIT:

After your last comment I realized that you need to group twice:

The first time you group by Breeder and day of birth to find the litters, then you group the result by Breeder to find the ones with more litters. Your aggregation should be the following:

```
    db.ped.aggregate([
    {
    $match: {
        "DOB-Year": 2014
    }
    },
    {
    $group: {
        _id: {
            "Breeder": "$Breeder",
            "DOB": "$DOB"
        },
        "count": {
            $sum: 1
        }
    }
    },
    {
    $group: {
        _id: {
            "Breeder": "$_id.Breeder"
        },
        "count": {
            $sum: 1
        }
    }
    },
    {
    $sort: {
        "count": -1
    }
    },
    {
    $limit: 15
    }
]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. Unfortunately there is something still not quite right about it. I think I'll post a response to explain since I seem to be limited by characters in a comment.